Is SunRace RDMS100 rear derailleur compatible with any non-SunRace shifter?
SunRace states in their FAQ that "For derailleurs and shifters the standard is Shimano-compatible [...]". With which Shimano shifter is their RDMS100 10-speed rear derailleur  compatible? Shimano uses at least three different cable pulls in 10-speed: road, Dyna-Sys and LinkGlide.
It's very likely that in this case SunRace would mean Dyna-Sys, as it appeared much earlier than LinkGlide, and the RD is kind of "not road"; but I'm looking for a confirmation.
Background: I'm considering switching to 1X drivetrain from Shimano 3X 10-speed. I don't care about bigger jumps between the gears, but I need wide range. Cassette must be replaced anyway to preserve the latter, which would also require RD able to handle bigger cogs. RDMS100 is 10-speed and can handle 51T (which AFAIK no Shimano 10-speed RD can), so if it's compatible with Dyna-Sys cable pull, I'd not need to replace the shifter.

The CUES 11sp group is cheap and can handle 51t cassette. No need to overcomplicate.

@Noise For CUES 11, I'll need 4 new parts (shifter, chain, cassette and RD). If SunRace is DynaSys compatible, I'd need only 2 parts. To me that's not "overcomplicate", that's the opposite.

It sounds like you don't have the cassette and are considering a change to 1X. Don't do the job twice! You also get the cranks in the groupset bundle.
